# What difference does the leading underscore make when naming React component files in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I'm just getting started with `React` in `Rails`.

When I come across other's `Rails` apps with `React`, I find some of them add a leading underscore when naming `*.js.*` files in `/app/assets/javascripts/components/`.
e.g. [Sample React Rails App](https://github.com/bensmithett/sample-react-rails-app/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/react_components)

Component files are like:

```
_comment.js.jsx
```

While some don't, 
e.g. [Account React Rails App](https://github.com/fervisa/accounts-react-rails/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/components)

Component files are like:

```
record.js.coffee
```

So what difference does it make to add the leading underscore?

I know in `Rails` view, naming a `*.html.erb` file with leading underscore means it's a partial which you can reuse and we call `render` method to render it. But here the `*.js.*` files are require by `components.js` with `//= require_tree ./components`. So even you remove the underscore, it makes no difference. And I believe this is the only part which "reuse" the component.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @Lahiru Is that my question isn't related to a specific problem I encounter?

Comment: Sorry, if my comment seems to be offensive. What I only meant was try to do some formatting with the provided markdown for others to understand it better :)

Comment: @Lahiru never mind, I'm just trying to figure out the right way. It's very nice of you to write the "suggested edits" for me.

Comment: In Rails using `_` as a prefix denotes that the file is a partial. A partial is a small piece of code that you can reuse in several other parts of your application.

Comment: @limelights Thanks! I've also been using partials in my rails views and call 'render' method to render the partial. But if they are all *.js.jsx files, likely that you can't call any rails method within those files. Can you provide an example of reusing the code in the [Sample React Rails App](https://github.com/bensmithett/sample-react-rails-app/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts/react_components)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's `//= require_tree ./components` in `application.js`. I think it really doesn't make any difference to name them with leading underscore.

Then I think there may be something to do with the Rails **asset pipeline**, because actually the `component` files are required duplicately in the **sample-react-rails-app**. The underscores might be for avoid duplication when precomiling.

I've tried remove the leading underscores in those file and run the app locally (also I make asset pipeline precompile in dev env). It turns out that even if you remove the leading underscores, **precompilation for those files still doesn't get duplicated and the app works just fine**. As a matter of fact, **asset pipeline** will only include the same file once even if you `require` the file duplicately.

In conclusion, the leading underscore **doesn't make any difference in how your app works**. It's probably a naming convention following **partial** naming like in **Rails views** or **SASS compilation** which was also mentioned in [Rails Issues #3094](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3094). And Generally I think the convention is worth following to tell yourself and your team those files work as incomplete parts.